# Why am I getting a syntax error on these joins?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm getting the

```
Syntax error in JOIN operation
```

error on this query.  This suggests that there's a misplaced parenthesis somewhere in the joins, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
select *
from
((ss
left join
sc
on
ss.guid=sc.guid)
left join
mrc
on
format(c.xDate, "yyyymmddHHMMSS")=mrc.xDate)
left join
c
on
sc.cID=c.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an error because `c` is referenced before it is defined:

```
select *
from ((ss left join
       sc
       on ss.guid = sc.guid
      ) left join
      mrc
      on format(c.xDate, "yyyymmddHHMMSS") = mrc.xDate
----------------^
     ) left join
     c
     on sc.cID = c.id
```

You can fix this by swapping the joins:

```
select *
from ((ss left join
       sc
       on ss.guid = sc.guid
      ) left join
      c
      on sc.cID = c.id
     ) left join
     mrc
     on format(c.xDate, "yyyymmddHHMMSS") = mrc.xDate
```